# Conditional results based on average found from other cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vlookup, worksheet-function

Rather than an Excel formula of this kind:

```
=IF(AVERAGE(A1:A4)<4,"POOR",IF(AVERAGE(A1:A4)<5,"Meet Expectation",IF(AVERAGE(A1:A4)<7,"Good",IF(AVERAGE(A1:A4)<8,"Excellent","Outstan‌​ding"))))
```

how might I achieve similar results with a lookup table?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: would you please show me example with lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lookup table (and without requiring an exact match):

[image]

Where an exacct match is not found it defaults to the next lower matching value. `9` can not be found but `8` can be, hence `Outstanding`. You have not been specific about the breakpoints (eg `5` seems to be both `Meet Expectation` and `Good`) but the table is easy to adjust to suit by adding or deducting a very small amount to the number to the left of `Good`.

The table is here named `Qarray` and can be placed anywhere in the same workbook if the named range is of Workbook scope.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula:

`=IF(A1<4,"POOR",IF(AND(A1>=4,A1<5),"Meets Expectations",IF(AND(A1>=5,A1<7),"Good",IF(AND(A1>=7,A1<8),"Excellent","Outstanding"))))`